# How do I turn an image in a numpy array into something I can put into a QLabel? (PyQt5)

Tags: python, numpy, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

Let have a video input from camera like this:

```py
    def create_local_tracks(self):
        global relay, webcam
        options = {"framerate": "30", "video_size": "640x480"}
        webcam = MediaPlayer("video=HP True Vision HD Camera", format='dshow', options=options)
        relay = MediaRelay()
        return relay.subscribe(webcam.video)

#somewhere in a class
self.server_webcamera_video = self.create_local_tracks()
self.videoTrack = WebCamera(self.server_webcamera_video,self.to_emitter)
pc.addTrack(self.videoTrack)
#self.video_blackHole = MediaBlackhole()
#self.video_blackHole.addTrack(self.videoTrack)
#await self.video_blackHole.start()

class WebCamera(MediaStreamTrack):
    kind = "video"

    def __init__(self,track,to_emitter):
        super().__init__()  # don't forget this!
        self.track = track
        self.to_emitter = to_emitter #Pipe to send data to QThread.
        
    async def recv(self):
        frame = await self.track.recv()
        #packet_bytes = frame.to_ndarray().tobytes()
        #self.to_emitter.send({"type":"server-web-camera-frame","frame":frame})
        #return None
        return frame
```

How can i display the video from web-camera in a pyqt5 application?

I want answers only related with [aiortc](https://aiortc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [PyAv.org](https://www.pyav.org)

Somehow with the QThread pyqtSignal will we have something like: `packet_bytes = frame.to_ndarray().tobytes()` where `frame`=[pyAv VideoFrame](https://pyav.org/docs/develop/api/video.html#av.video.frame.VideoFrame) what can i do with the bytes to put it into a QLabel for example?